# How to remove a specific array from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

i.e if ArrayList contains coordinates {0, 0} remove them.

Code test below fails as expected.

```
ArrayList<int[]> array = new ArrayList<>();

int[] arr1 = new int[]{0, 0};
int[] arr2 = new int[]{1, 1};

array.add(arr1);
array.add(arr2);

System.out.println("Before " + array.contains(arr1)); // true

int[] arr3 = new int[]{0, 0};

array.remove(arr3);

System.out.println("After " + array.contains(arr1)); //true
```

Comment: `System.out.println("After " + array.contains(arr1)); //true` - actually that prints `After false`, since you are removing the exact same array instance you added to the List.

Comment: Code runs fine as expected. Your last line prints false

Comment: See this :https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/arraylist/remove-element-from-arraylist/

Comment: try printing `array.contains(arr3)` just before removing it

Comment: Note: `remove` only removes first found element (if it would work with arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `removeIf` like so :

```
array.removeIf(a-> a[0] == 0 && a[1] == 0);
```

or you can use :

```
array.removeIf(a -> Arrays.equals(a, new int[]{0, 0}));
```

Of if you want to remove all the arrays which contains only zeros you can use :

```
array.removeIf(a -> Arrays.stream(a).allMatch(value -> value == 0));
```

After the edit of the OP the solution can be like so :

```
array.removeIf(a -> Arrays.equals(a, arr3));
```

Comment: @raviraja the OP ask to remove each array in the ArrayList which hold {0, 0}, maybe he/she gives the wrong example

Comment: we can rather use this statement  array.removeIf(a->a.equals(arr1)); . why use Array class?

Comment: @SujayMohan no, equals doesnt check element by element but it check the reference you can check the two examples here http://www.ideone.com/jTNlmK and http://www.ideone.com/6NJWAT

Comment: @SujayMohan and that is the same that `remove()` does

Comment: @SujayMohan in your example it will remove the correct array because you will remove an existing array, but the general idea of the OP is to any array which hold {0, 0}, the OP edit his/her answer